# Appended element goes undefined when being passed over

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

Hi i have this code where everclick appends a DOM element where the user can pick what he wants then submits it to another page.

```
<form action="view.php" method="post">
<textarea name="paragraph[]"></textarea><input type="button" onclick="addparagraph();" value="+">
</input>
<select name="font[]">
<option>Tohoma</option>
<option>Arial</option>
</select>
<div id="firstpart"></div>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
function addparagraph(){
  var string = '<textarea name="paragraph[]"></textarea>'+
  '<select name="font[]"><option>Tohoma</option><option>Arial</option></select>';
  jQuery('#firstpart').append(string);
}
</script>
```

once submitted it does not get the value of the appended elements

here is the view.php part

```
foreach($_POST['paragraph'] as $count => $value){
  echo "$value";
  echo "$_POST['font'][$count];
}
```

it appends the elements but it does not display the values of the appended array.. it gives an error offset undefined

Comment: I don't see a closing select tag

Comment: sorry i missed it i just created the code here i did not copy and pasted it

Comment: What about the first select tag.  It's not closed either

Comment: Still you have quotes issue in your jquery code

Comment: Need to be `function addparagraph(){
  var string = '<textarea name="paragraph[]"></textarea>'+'<select name="font[]"><option>Tohoma</option><option>Arial</option></select>';
  jQuery('#firstpart').append(string);
}`

Comment: It also looks like you are creating multiple selects with the same font[] name.

Comment: yes it should be it is an array..

Comment: var_dump your $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You need to add a jQuery library to make your code to work.

2.You need to change PHP code too.

The code needs to be like below:-

***HTML PAGE:-***

```
<form action="view.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="paragraph[]"></textarea><input type="button" onclick="addparagraph();" value="+"></input>
    <select name="font[]">
        <option>Tohoma</option>
        <option>Arial</option>
    </select>
    <div id="firstpart"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function addparagraph(){
  var string = '<textarea name="paragraph[]"></textarea>'+'<select name="font[]"><option>Tohoma</option><option>Arial</option></select>';
  jQuery('#firstpart').append(string);
}
</script>
```

***PHP PAGE:-***

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['paragraph'] as $key => $value){
  echo $value;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $_POST['font'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should look like this:

```
  foreach($_POST['paragraph'] as $count => $value){
  echo $value;
  echo $_POST['font'][$count];
}
```

Comment: it is a offset of the array? like font[0] or font[1]